# i can not setup installation of ros

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have 14.10 ubuntu. Please help me. I can not do installation. due to 14.10 or else

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200275/i-can-not-setup-installation-of-ros/) by [ayana](https://answers.ros.org/users/21064/ayana/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-12-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-01-02**:
Duplicate of [ubuntu 14.10 and ros installation error help me](http://answers.ros.org/question/200276/ubuntu-1410-and-ros-installation-error-help-me/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

14.10 will be supported in the next ROS release. 14.10 has come out since the last ROS release.

If you need to keep that machine you can use a VM or Docker until the next release is available in May. There will be prereleases also available before the final release.

Target platforms are documented in [REP 3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) Updates for the next release, Jade, is under review [here](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep/pull/89)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-01-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0